# Creation of AMI image, make public through boto

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto, creation, amazon-ami

I can't figure out through the botot docs and google search to create an ami image and make it public from the beginning.  I can create an ami image, but it is always private.  I can only make public afterward through the AWS panel.

This is my code to just create an image that is only private.

```
image_id = self.conn.create_image(instance_id,name,no_reboot=no_reboot,dry_run=dry_run)
```

Answer (score 2):

AMI image is created as private. There is no way to create them as public. After creation you can make them public using Boto/CLI or make them accessible for other accounts.

Call `modify_image_attribute()` after the image is created

```
self.conn.modify_image_attribute('image-id', groups='all')
```

Comment: thanks for the reply!  how do you make it public through boto?  the library doesn't seem to offer that option.  only the web interface does?